# How can I find out who is using my Windows Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)?

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring, internet-sharing

This is related to the question, "[Can I monitor who is using my Mac OS X Internet Sharing?](https://superuser.com/questions/48611/can-i-monitor-who-is-using-my-mac-os-x-internet-sharing)" but while that deals with Mac OS X, my questions is about Windows XP.

How do I find out who is sharing my internet connection on XP Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately none that I know of. ICS is a very basic connection sharing mechanism which lacks many protocol features that would allow for client monitoring such as you are looking for.

That said, it is possible that you may be able to see this in an indirect manner by the help of the netstat command in the console. I'm thinking that something like

**netstat -a -o**

Will allow you to match the PID column with the ICS process ID under Task Manager and infer any connected ICS clients whether they are currently actively using the connection or just idle.

But... I'm not so sure about that and I can't currently test this. I'll leave you with the that thought though.

**So what else can be done?**
The answer is to use alternate solutions to Windows ICS.

Router: Use a router and you can remove ICS altogether. The router shares the connection and any decent one will provide you with all the data you need.

Software Gateways: Very popular in the late 90s and early 00s and still strong alternatives to ICS. These are essentially *software routers* or proxy servers. Programs like [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com/) or [AnalogX Proxy](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/proxy/Freeware.htm) give you the ability to replace ICS functionality with their own while providing better statistical and monitoring abilities. AnalogX doesn't do the latter though. Just there because it's yet another proxy I'm familiar with. But WinGate is the mother of connection sharing and monitoring.

I'd personally choose the router solution. Much more extensible, easier to manage, saves you from Yet-Another-Windows-Service, very powerful in terms of possible features, and comparatively inexpensive these days.

Answer (score 1):

You might use network monitoring tools to find out which machines are currently in your network segment.
Some tools are:

[Nmap](http://nmap.org/)
It was designed to rapidly scan large networks, but works fine against single hosts. Requires WinPcap.

[Angry IP](http://www.angryip.org/w/About)
is a very lightweight program that allows you to quickly scan a range of IP addresses. It provides less information and options than Nmap, but shows open ports and highlights which addresses are active.