# Find devices connected to mac os via internet sharing

Tags: macos, internet-sharing

I used Internet sharing in my mac os x to share my Ethernet internet via my wifi.

I want to know who is connected to my wifi and how much traffic he use. Is there any tools to find the connected devices and show the amount of their traffics?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arp` tool like so:

```
arp -i en1 -a
```

It will display all clients connected via WLAN. The `-i` parameter specifies which interface to use.

Here's the official documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/arp.8.html

> **NAME**
>
> ```
>  arp -- address resolution display and control
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The arp utility displays and modifies the Internet-to-Ethernet address
> translation tables used by the address resolution protocol (arp(4)).
> With no flags, the program displays the current ARP entry for
> hostname. The host may be specified by name or by number, using
> Internet dot notation.

Here's another solution from a similar question: https://superuser.com/a/48615/265073

As for the amount of traffic used, you can try to use the following software:

- [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) provides a nice GUI for displaying all traffic that passes through your machine. You can configure it to only capture the traffic that comes from the shared internet connection;
- [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is a similar tool for command-line, so it doesn't have a GUI. It allows you to see all the traffic on a specified interface.

These applications can solve your problem, but they will both require you to read the manuals extensively, because they have a lot of built-in functionality and are somewhat complicated.